# Como debo instalar el plugin en eslint

Tags: javascript, plugin

Quiero instalar el eslint-plugin-jsx-ally pero me sale este error

```
> eslint-plugin-jsx-ally@6.0.3 postinstall
```

que debo hacer

Comment: eso no es un error. al menos pon la traza completa para que podamos ver lo que ocurre

Comment: Error: This is the wrong package! Please install eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint-plugin-jsx-ally\postinstall.js:1:69)

Comment: el error te indica que instales el modulo: `npm install eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y --save-dev`

Comment: lo instalo y me sale lo mismo

Comment: estás usando el modulo `eslint-config-airbnb`? en ese caso debes seguir unas instreucciones especificas. Viene todo aqui: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y

Comment: has leido bien mi comentario de antes? el nombre del modulo es distinto

Answer (score 0):

Es (lamentablemente) común que en el registro de npm algunas personas publiquen paquetes con nombres parecidos a uno existente para que alguien los instale sin querer (y son paquetes potencialmente dañinos).

Otras veces alguien despublica un paquete y rápidamente otro desarrollador publica un paquete con el nombre que se acaba de liberar, capturando a los que tienen ese paquete entre sus dependencias.

Aparentemente tu caso es simplemente que el paquete [eslint-plugin-jsx-ally](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-ally) no es el correcto, sino que debes instalar [eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y).

Para asegurarse de que nadie instalara el primero, su autor puso a propósito un error en el hook `postinstall`.

Revisando:

```
npm view eslint-plugin-jsx-ally
```

el hook `postinstall` llama explícitamente a `node ./postinstall.js` cuyo contenido es justamente

```
throw new Error('This is the wrong package! Please install eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y')
```